# Programmatically read comments on a Google Docs?

Tags: java, javascript, api, parsing, google-drive-api

I have a client who wishes to create a program that compiles a list of comments from Google Docs. Is there a way to access Google Doc's comments through a scraper or perhaps an official API? I tried using JSOUP to get the information, but Google states that "javascript is unsupported on you browser" resulting in no text being generated. Any ideas for how to programmatically get a list of comments?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list and for java: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Comments.Get.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Drive API's `comments` resource to list the comments of a doc, samples and reference are available on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list